# Mongoose/MongoDb ,how to validate an array of Ids against another model

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have 2 moongose Schema:

```
var Schema2 = new Schema({
    creator : { type: String, ref: 'User'},
    schema_name : [{ type: String}],
});

var Schema1 = new Schema({
    creator : { type: String, ref: 'User'},
    schema_ref : [{ type: String, ref: 'Schema2' }],
});
```

Would like to know which is the best practice when I create a new Schema1 check that every element of array schema_ref, have the same creator.

Because schema1 elements are added by client form and so i have to check that the schema_ref elements are owned by same User that send the form

Comment: Have a look this mongoose validation: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with either validator function, or with a simple 'save' middleware:

```
Schema1.pre('save', function(next) {
    let owner;
    for (let entry in this.schema_ref) {
        if (!owner) {
            owner = entry;
        } else {
            if (entry !== owner) {
                return next(new Error("owner mismatch");
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Also, your schema might not work as you expect it to, it looks like you actually need:

```
schema_ref: [{
    type: {type: String},
    ref: "User"
}]
```

Additionally, take a look at id-validator plugin, or some similar to that - it will, in addition to your validation, also check that all ref-type properties like this actually exist in the other (Users) collection.